Can I use the Copy-PnPFolder to copy local files to SharePoint?
I'm trying to use the command below to copy local files to SharePoint.
Copy-PnPFolder -LocalPath "C:\Projects\BS\Banner.zip" -TargetUrl "https://Demo.sharepoint.com/sites/Demo/Documents" -Overwrite -Recurse 

But getting error:
Copy-PnPFile : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'LocalPath'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Copy-PnPFolder -LocalPath 

I'm using the following PNP.Powersehll version
1.11.0     PnP.PowerShell
Powershell Version
5.1.22621.3672
Does these versions support the parameter?

Ability to upload files and folders from the local folder to SharePoint online using PnP PowerShell is recently added to PnP PowerShell module.
It is not available in PnP PowerShell version 1.11.0. It is currently available in Nightly release version.
So, try these steps once:

Uninstall all previously installed PnP PowerShell versions using:

Uninstall-Module PnP.PowerShell -AllVersions


Install current Nightly build of PnP PowerShell using:

Install-Module PnP.PowerShell -Scope CurrentUser -AllowPrerelease -SkipPublisherCheck


Try running Copy-PnPFolder command again. Example:

Copy-PnPFolder -LocalPath "c:\temp" -TargetUrl "Subsite1/Shared Documents" -Recurse -Overwrite

References:

Installing PnP PowerShell
Copy-PnPFolder


Thanks and will give that a shot

Sure, let me know how it goes.

THanks Ganesh. Is this suppose towork with Powershell Version 5.1.22621.3672.
Or i need to upgrade to PS version 7?

You need PowerShell v7.2 or later to use PnP PowerShell.
